# Local variable 'mydate' might not be initialized before accessing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my code i initilized Datetime like this

```
 DateTime myDate;
```

But when i try to access it then i got this error.

> Local variable 'myDate' might not be initialized before accessing

Here i initialized my date know ?

Answer (score 20):

You *declared* it, but you didn't give it a value; you can't ***read*** a local variable until it is "definitely assigned". For a simple example:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.UtcNow; // is assigned
```

You don't have to give it a value right away... you can give it a value any time before you try to read it, including any branching etc that leaves no ambiguity that it has a value, for example:

```
DateTime myDate;
//....
if(condition) {
    myDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
} else {
    myDate = GetDateFromSomewhereElse();
}
Console.WriteLine(myDate);
```

For contrast, *fields* (class variables) are automatically initialized to their all-zero value, and are treated as "definitely assigned" from the object's creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to initialize, just declare `DataTime myDate = null`. But remember to judge if it is null when you use it.